# Use toolbar to navigate properly

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, toolbar, swift2

I'm trying to do a instagram-like (or any app with a toolbar in fact) toolbar, to navigate from screens to screens.

I have a navigation controller, with 5 screens, and I already did this :

- In each screen, in the viewDidLoad, I put:

`self.toolbarItems = self.navigationController!.toolbarItems`

- And in the navigationController, for one BartbuttonItem I have this
  function for example:

`@IBAction func profileButtonClicked(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
self.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(false)
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showProfile", sender: self)
}`

So it is working, but I don't like the transition when I go first to the navigationController then to the newViewController, I would like there is no transition at all.

I would be thankful if you help me.

Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FOUND :

just needed to uncheck "Animates", when you click on the segue in the storyBoard and then go to Attributes Inspector and just uncheck this checkbox.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Click the view Controller on main storyboard
2. Then go to attribute inspector
3. There is a option called transition style, choose cross dissolve

   OR Use

   ```
     self.sourceViewController.presentViewController(self.destinationViewController as! UIViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
   ```

Comment: Hi, I tried, but this is not working, I still see the first viewController (rootedViewController) :/

Comment: select all viwcontrollers and do as above then run , still got output like this ?

Comment: Yes this is what I just did and I still have no differences

Comment: This is kind of working, but not really, because then when I use the backButton from the push segue, I arrived onto the 2nd viewController, and not the RootViewController

Comment: For example, with your solution, if I click 5 times on the button, then I will have 5 click on the backButton to get to my first one..